# nifi redirect through aws accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-nifi, amazon-sqs

This is likely a very niche question.

I have a nifi system set up external to AWS it reads from an sqs queue and then puls files from an s3 bucket
I have a role set on the account.
but I now have a need to watch an sqs queue and pull from an s3 bucket on a different account.

I need to have my nifi access my account and then pull from a different teams sqs queue they have  created an arn for my iam role to switch to.

Is this possible. I dont know if I need to change the queue URL in the GetSQS processor soit doesn't point directly at their queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AWSCredentialsProviderService in nifi to assume the role from my account to theirs and allows you to wathch their queue and then pull from their S3

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but not with GetSQS since there is no incoming connection to it.

1 - Use ExecuteStreamingCmd to get the SQS msg and redirect to a FetchS3 or what action you have post SQS fetch.

2 - Use GetSQS in combination with a registry variable. The workaround here would be for you to trigger the variable value swap and then triger your getsqs.

3 - This is the easy one - create separate flow.

Comment: I've sorted it now. you can use AWSCredentialsProviderService in nifi to assume the role from my account to theirs and allows you to wathch their queue and then pull from their S3. thanks though